# Provide a default implementation for a protocol method returning an associatedtype

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete, swift-protocols, associated-types

I have this basic protocol:

```swift
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype Content: View
    @MainActor @ViewBuilder func content() -> Content
}
```

I want to provide a default implementation for `content()`, so I figured I'd do this:

```swift
extension MyProtocol {
    @MainActor @ViewBuilder func content() -> some View {
        EmptyView()
    }
}
```

That works. However, now autocompletion in conforming types does something strange. Instead of making the return type `some View`, it uses `Content`, which does not compile:

```swift
struct Implementation: MyProtocol {
    func content() -> Content { // Auto-completed, does not compile
        Text("ABC")
    }
}
```

I have to manually fix the return type:

```swift
struct Implementation: MyProtocol {
    func content() -> some View { // Now it compiles
        Text("ABC")
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Comment: Your protocol has an associated type that needs to be defined in a conforming type and this is what you do indirectly in your second solution but not in the first one. And I don't think the default implementation has anything to do with this.

Comment: Yeah, but if I leave out the "default implementation", everything works fine and auto-complete puts `some View` as the return type, which is what I would expect. All I need is for the compiler to auto-complete the "correct" return type. Maybe I lack the understanding of what's exactly causing this.

Comment: Oh, so this is about auto-completion. I didn't get that, I just pasted your code into a playground and tested it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough on that

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment section, the issue is that the associatedtype `Content` is not yet defined when you are trying to use autocompletion.
If you define `Content` with a typealias **before** implementing the `content()` func autocompletion will behave as expected. ie:

```swift
struct Implementation: MyProtocol {
    typealias Content = Text
    
    func content() -> Text {
        <#code#>
    }
}
```